# Upload File and Display in the same page

Tags: jquery, html

HTML:

```
<input name="fileToUpload" type="file" id="fileToUpload"/>
<div id="div1"> </div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(function()
{
   $("#fileToUpload").on('change', 'input' ,  function(){
   // Display image on the page for viewing
        readURL(this,"div1");

   });
});

function readURL(input , tar) {  
if (input.files && input.files[0]) { // got sth

    // Clear image container
    $("#" + tar ).empty(); 

    $.each(input.files , function(index,ff)  // loop each image 
    {

        var reader = new FileReader();

        // Put image in created image tags
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#' + tar).attr('src', e.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(ff);

    });
}
```

I want to display the image uploaded to the div container however my code doesn't work. Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: you could try this way - 
http://www.w3bees.com/2013/08/ajax-image-upload-with-jquery.html
ajax and server end php

Comment: Can you add a fiddle?

Comment: @user3029017 i dont want to save the file. I just want to display the image.

Comment: @Jonny erm.. i dont know how to user fiddle :|

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, that you are

1. trying to set the src attribute on a div
2. using the second argument of on() incorrectly (it is a selector string to filter the **descendants of the selected elements** that trigger the event)

`$("#fileToUpload").on('change', 'input' ,  function(){`

becomes

`$("#fileToUpload").on('change', function(){`

and your div becomes an img.

Full solution:

```html
<input name="fileToUpload" type="file" id="fileToUpload"/>
<img id="preview" />
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("#fileToUpload").on('change', function() {
    // Display image on the page for viewing
    readURL(this, "preview");

  });
});

function readURL(input, tar) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) { // got sth

    // Clear image container
    $("#" + tar).removeAttr('src');

    $.each(input.files, function(index, ff) // loop each image 
      {

        var reader = new FileReader();

        // Put image in created image tags
        reader.onload = function(e) {
          $('#' + tar).attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(ff);

      });
  }
}
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u7ww6bwv/

Comment: Thanks. I will try it out

Comment: It is not working. But i have this error message --> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: yan, please make sure you included jQuery as an external resource.